# Pascal case not working right

Tags: case, pascal

Ill be straight to it, how can I make this menu work right? When I run the program and want to select 1 the program just pauses and when I press a another button it just closes.

How can I make the program to read(show whats in it) and use the selection I choose from the menu?

```
program project1;
uses crt;

Var
izv: Integer;

begin
clrscr;

   Writeln('1. selection');
   Writeln('2. selection');
   Writeln('3. selection');
   Writeln('4. selection');
   writeln;
   writeln('choose: ');

   if izv = 1 then
          begin
             writeln('1. selection');      
          end;

   if izv = 2 then
       begin
        writeln('2. selection');    
        end;

      if izv = 3 then
       begin
        writeln('3. selection');
        end;

     if izv = 4 then
       begin
       writeln('4. selection');
      end;

Readkey;
```

end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not reading the `izv` variable. You should use [readln()](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/system/readln.html) to read the user input.

Comment: And above the tests of izv. Another solution is a  keypressed/readkey combination in a loop.